# How do I find which assembly I need to reference in order to use a certain namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Ok, so this is a common occurrence for me:  Through docs on MSDN, or other people's code snippets, I've found a class or namespace I want to use in my project, but I don't know which assembly I need to add in order to make that class or namespace available.

I've found lots of information about how to find out what namespaces a dll exports, but not much for going in the other direction.

I'd really prefer not to have to manually search through every dll on my machine.  Is there a list/tool/resource somewhere that I can go to for this information?  For the standard .NET/WPF classes at least?

Comment: Ah, I see it lists the assembly on the root page of the docs for a class!  I was looking on the namespace page.  Want to submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for the class on [msdn.microsoft.com/library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library) and it will list the namespace there. For example, for [StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter(v=vs.110).aspx):

### StringWriter Class

#### Namespace:  System.IO

#### Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

Answer (score 2):

Go To View --> Object Browser and Choose All Components from the browse dropdown box. And search your name. And you see the results...